# How to get Context in an Intent Service

Tags: android, intentservice

Here's the scenario: I have a WakefulBroadcastReceiver that does a
backup to a network computer or the cloud. It's set to go off in the
middle of the night, when I know the tablet will have access to the
LAN. The backup will store the data to a location and a file that was "picked" by the fragment that instantiated the WakefulBroadcastReceiver, 
using the Storage Access Framework. So I need to be able to access the
ContentResolver and to do that I need the context.

From all my reading of the documents, this is what the
BroadcastReceiver is meant to be used for - a potentially long running
task that should be done in the background when not much else is
happening. - Like a backup. I just haven't seen any examples that puts
everything together.

How do I get the context in an IntentService? Here
is a snippet of the receiver and the scheduling service.

```
  public class BackupAlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            Intent service = new Intent(context, BackupSchedulingService.class);

        startWakefulService(context, service);

        }
}

public class BackupSchedulingService extends IntentService {
    public BackupSchedulingService() {
        super("BackupSchedulingService");
    }

 @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras(); 
        // How to get the context - it was a parameter when
        // creating the new IntentService class above? 
         }
}
```

The example code pretty much follows exactly the Android reference
manual code here:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html

Answer (score 88):

> So my question is how do I get the context in an IntentService?

The `IntentService` *is* the `Context`, as `IntentService` inherits from `Context`.

Answer (score 39):

Just call `getApplicationContext()`

Comment: What is the difference between 'getApplicationContext()' and using 'this' ?

Comment: it does work in
"protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {"
but not in the IntentService constructor

Comment: @Moises can you explain why?

Answer (score 9):

You can get the context in onStartCommand() function.

```
    public class ExampleService extends IntentService {
    private Context mContext;

    public ExampleService(String name) {
    super(name);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    mContext = getApplicationContext();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **BackupSchedulingService.this** (ServiceName.this) to get Context

*Reason*:
       Service extends ContextWrapper
       ContextWrapper extends Context

Answer (score 2):

You can use Intent service class as Context. because this is the hierarchy of [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) class.

- android.content.Context

  - android.content.ContextWrapper

    - android.app.Service

      - android.app.IntentService

So In **java**

`BackupSchedulingService.this`

And in **Kotlin**

```
this@BackupSchedulingService
```

Hope this will help future devs...